# how to nest pseudo element inside another psedo element in scss

Tags: html, css, sass

im trying to add some custom styles to title attribute in scss, i found a resource which show how to do this in css, basically it nest one pseudo element inside another,

```
[data-title]:hover::before {

    content: attr(data-title);

}
```

how can i convert this nesting in to scss?

below is the link which i refer, it use css, i want it on scss,
https://codepen.io/shimdim/pen/NjyNNb

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You coould try it like this:

Use `&:hover:after {}` for targeting the after pseudo-element of the element being hovered over.

`&:after:hover {}` would select the after pseudo-element and used on hover it.

Comment: thank you this appear to be working in a mock i create on codepen but didnt work inside the project, but this seems like the correct way, for any one interested below is the codepen 

https://codepen.io/lakmalkaviratne/pen/NWKEBJe